# How to add menu bar to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, browser, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons

Is there any way to add menu bar in Google Chrome? I didn't find such an option in menu so perhaps it is available with some extention.

The the bar that is on the top of the window which contains drop-down menus like "file", "edit" or "view".

To be clear I don't mean opening the menu of the button in the upper left corner.

Comment: What kind of menu bar? You mean Bookmark bar?

Comment: No. I mean the bar that is on the top of the window which contains drop-down menus like "file", "edit" or "view".

Comment: On Windows, OSX, Linux, BSD?

Comment: Oh sorry,  I forgot to specify. On Windows 10.

Comment: It's not there at all, or you'd like to add it permanently. Does it appear when you press Alt?

Comment: It is not there at all. Pressing alt does nothing.

Comment: And to be clear I don't mean opening the menu of the button in the upper left corner

Answer (score 2):

Not in Chrome, but possible in some other Chromium-powered browsers (still able to use Chrome extensions, but not necessarily Google Sync).
Most notably, the Vivaldi browser.

On Chrome, only the OSX builds the file-menu.

Answer (score 1):

Google's Chrome/Chromium doesn't have a "File, Edit, View..." menu bar like you're asking about.

They only have the "Hamburger" / "Customize and Control" menu button, usually in the upper left. Pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> should open it.
[image: Hamburger]

<sub>FYI - [A Brief History of the "Hamburger" Icon](https://blog.placeit.net/history-of-the-hamburger-icon/)</sub>

- [Info on using the "Hamburger"](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/enabling-google-chrome-menu-bar-78783.html)
- [Google Chrome Help Forum - how to display menu bar in google chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/TfCIsMvQTXY)

  > If you are looking to click on File to perform an Edit and/or View action, you can find these within the ≡ icon at the top right of the Chrome browser.

It's conceivable that there exists some app / extension that reproduces a Menu Bar of some type, there are some like ["Menu Bar"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/menu-button/goblmaagcgfbjlaahdohiomenekdpnci?hl=en-US) or ["Context Menus"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/context-menus/phlfmkfpmphogkomddckmggcfpmfchpn?hl=en-US) that sound promising...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are talking not about something included in Google Chrome, but rather in a Google Product, such as Google Docs, Google Slides, Google Drawings, et cetera, which have those drop down menus.

No, you cannot add these drop down menus to Google Chrome, as they are drop down menus that serve the purpose of editing a file, i.e., their purpose is to modify things.

Comment: I think the question is referring to the kind of menu bar you can add in Firefox.  The question was about whether you could add that type of menu to Chrome (many people find access to that functionality useful in a browser; it isn't just for modifying a file).